# Two good answers, so how do I select one to accept?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I have a question about my Web Applications Stack Exchange post: [Make Startpage search results page bold or highlight keywords used](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/122427/make-startpage-search-results-page-bold-or-highlight-keywords-used)

[One answerer tells me exactly what is happening about the startpage](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/122428/200642), while [another answerer tells me how to solve my problem](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/122432/200642). I can't figure out which one I should accept.

Comment: This is definitely a personal choice.  I don't feel comfortable steering you one way or the other. If they are both good answers, they will ultimately get their share of upvotes, which in some ways are more meaningful than the check mark.

Comment: @jonsca Are you meaning if  I no idea to select one, then I should leave that question no any accept?

Comment: I was simply saying the decision is up to you.  In the long run, if they both get 30 upvotes and one has an accept, people will be reassured that they are both quality answers.  You should select the one that best answers your question as the answer, but you are within your rights not to select either, if that's what you so choose. In the end, it's not a lifetime decision, and you could switch to the other answer in the future if it's edited to be more appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This gets asked quite a lot, especially at [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13396/21960) (which is the Meta for the entire Stack Exchange network).

Basically, it's your choice, but you can still only choose one.

- Some suggest upvoting all the answers that are useful, and accepting the one you actually use
- Some suggest to upvote those that are helpful but only accept one. Accepting gives +15 reputation to the author, whereas upvoting gives +10 reputation to the author.
- Others suggest that if you can't choose, don't. It is not a *requirement* that you accept anything.
- Some suggest you accept the answer that is the most comprehensive and easiest to understand.

So, really, it's entirely up to you based on whatever criteria are important to you.

Comment: you can also leave a comment why you choose this but not that